# Developing mobile substrate tweak

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, tweak

What kinds of iphone functions can be over rided and how can i find and look at these functions? Or where can i look at them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class-dump-z to dump the class headers from a binary. For example, you could class dump the headers from SpringBoard to view what functions you can hook.

I recommend using Theos to write your tweaks. It's a really nice platform that is easy to use, and is also well documented.

iphonedevwiki.net is a good wiki for all the unofficial development information.

Hope this was of some use!

Josh

Theos: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started

class-dump-z: http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z

Comment: Thanks for showing me class dump but i moved it to /bin on my phone and chmoded it to executable but now when i do class-dump-z SpringBoard.app it says

Comment: An exception was thrown while analyzing 'SpringBoard.app' (with sysroot '/'):

Comment: You need to dump headers from the binary... not the folder. The binary is in SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard :) I'd appreciate it if you marked this as the answer.

Comment: Im reading over everything that was in SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard Dang its so much !